# How to express Switch to stand-by and Switch off in french?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire

I'm looking for the words to express 'Switch to stand-by' and 'Switch off' (i.e. power completely off) in French?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a translation:

> *“Switch to stand-by”* can be said with *« Mettre en veille »*
>
> *“Switch off”* can be said with *« Éteindre »*

Comment: If talking about big machinery, *switch off* can also be translated to *mettre hors tension*.

Comment: Yes, we're talking about big machines here - not TVs etc.

Comment: Switch off: éteindre, couper, arrêter.